# why std::cin in step 3 is omitted?

Tags: c++

I don't understand, why `cin >> W;` in step 3 is omitted, if i input not a number (i.e. 's').

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  short W = -1;

  cout << "step 1) W = " << W << endl;
  cout << "give a number: ";
  cin >> W;

  if ( cin.fail() )
  {
    cout << "ERROR, bad number" << endl;
    W = -1;

    cout << endl << "step 2) W == " << W << endl;
    cin.clear();
  }

  cout << endl << "step 3) W == " << W << endl;
  cout << "give a number: ";
  cin >> W;

  cout << endl << "step 4) W == " << W << endl;

  system("PAUSE");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I think this code is more on how you should use `cin >>` and `cout <<`.  Needless to say, it's quite a horrible code; so don't use it as your inspiration.

Comment: notnoop: maybe it is horrbile, but i want to understand why does it work such way, not why does it look like so horrible ..

Comment: Don't forget to accept Steffen's answer, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming, you are puzzled by the case where you enter a non-number for step 1 and then the step 3 seems not to work.

The problem is, that cin.clear() clears only the error flags of the stream. The wrong input is not taken out of the stream, so the next `cin >> W` just reads the same wrong input again.

You can for example fill a string from cin which takes everything or you can use `cin.ignore()` to ignore the following characters in the input stream.

See http://www.arachnoid.com/cpptutor/student1.html for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: the problem is that i've tried to put one / two `cin.ignore();` inside if block, and it seems it doesn't work .. that's why i am confused about 'how it really works'

Comment: ok, i got it, `cin.clear();` have to be **BEFORE** 'cin.ignore();` not after .. thank you for the link .. now i understand what does mean 'broken stream' .. now, the post can be CLOSED